# how send email confirmation to customer when return product RMA prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Please can anyone help me !
i would like to send email to customer that notify 
her request is in progress after he want return product.
prestashop 1.6

big thanx

Comment: Matteo Emma ,  i use Prestashop 1.6 but i like a function auto-generate (automatically send mail ) when customer return Marchandise ..

Answer (score 0):

is a setting you can do from backend.
You must go to order and then on status.

At this point, or create a new state, or modify an existing one. You can find the "model" select to bottom.

Comment: Matteo Emma , i use Prestashop 1.6 but i like a function auto-generate (automatically send mail ) when customer return Marchandise that confirm her request in progress ...